# Angular 2 not able to call Custom Web Api using asp.net MVC 5 Web Api

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-web-api2, angular2-routing

I have a problem calling Custom Web Api in asp.net MVC 5.The following is my code for Web Api Controller and angular js 2.

```
 [Route("api/email/detail/{id:int}"), HttpGet]
 public async Task<IHttpActionResult> EmailDetail(int id)
 {
     return Ok();
 }
```

The code for angular app.routing.ts is as follows:

```
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home.component';
import { UserComponent } from './components/user.component';
import { EmailComponent } from './components/email.component';
import { EmailDetail } from './components/email.detail';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'App/Template', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'user', component: UserComponent },
    { path: 'detail/:id', component: EmailDetail },
    { path: 'email', component: EmailComponent },
    //{ path: 'detail', component: EmailDetail},
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

Code for email.detail.ts is as follows:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { UserService } from '../Service/user.service';
import { IEmail } from '../Models/user';

import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';


@Component({
    templateUrl: 'About/Template/Detail'
})

export class EmailDetail implements OnInit {
    private emailId: number;
    private email: IEmail

    constructor(private _userService: UserService, private _http: Http, 
    private route: ActivatedRoute) {

    }

    ngOnInit(): void {

        this._http.get("api/email/detail/1992").subscribe(data => {
            // Read the result field from the JSON response.
        });

    }
}
```

The error I get in the console is as follows:
[The api call is http://localhost:16552/detail/api/email/detail/1992 and detail is getting prepended which is preventing from calling the api controller.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTc3M.png)

Comment: try changing `RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)` to `RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes,{useHash:true})` in `app.routing.ts`

Comment: should there be detail 2 times in your URL? where is your base url in angular?

Comment: No 'detail' is getting prepended before the custom api route to make it http://localhost:16552/detail/api/email/detail/1992 which should not happen.

Also my code for base url is :
@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, ReactiveFormsModule, HttpModule, routing, Ng2Bs3ModalModule],
    declarations: [AppComponent, UserComponent, HomeComponent, EmailComponent, EmailDetail],
    providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/' }, UserService],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

Comment: useHash solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

useHash solved the problem and its working fine now.